# A proof about accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis

The question is: Assume that a sequence {$u_n$} which satisfies |$u_{n+1}$ — $u_{n}$|→0. Define L(u) as the set of all the accumulation points of {$u_n$}.

Show that, if a,b ∈ L(u) and $\mathit l$ ∈ [a,b], then $\mathit l$ ∈ L(u).

Furthermore, what will happen if a or b is infinity?

I've been suffering from being unable to solve this problem clearly. I really hope to see a watertight proof for this classic problem.

Answer (score 0):

$b=\infty$ is OK. For any $c\in(a, b)$ and any $0<\epsilon<\min(b-c, c-a)$, take $N_1$ so that $n>N_1$ implies $|u_{n+1}-u_n|<\epsilon$. If there is $N\geq N_1$ so that for all $n>N$ we have $u_n\notin (c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$, then either for all $n>N$ we have $u_n\leq c-\epsilon$, or for all $n>N$ we have $u_n\geq c+\epsilon$. That contradicts the fact both $a<c-\epsilon$ and $b>c+\epsilon$ are limit points of the $u$ sequence.